# Request body could not be parsed. Make sure request body matches specified content-type: application/json

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am calling an API with the below code at the server side. It keeps bringing the error: **Request body could not be parsed. Make sure request body matches specified content-type: application/json**

**The Server side code is below:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> BVNMatch()
    {
        var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paystack_SecretKey"];
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.paystack.co/bvn/match"))
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {secretKey}");
                request.Content = new StringContent("{ bvn: \"22******\",\n      account_number: \"068*****\",\n      bank_code: \"034\",\n      first_name: \"uth***\",\n      last_name: \"ji***\"\n  }");
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                BVNMatch myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BVNMatch>(jsonString);
                return Json(myDeserializedClass);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Below is the client side Ajax call:**

```
 // Testing the BVNMatch Paystack API
                $("#btnGetBVN").click(function () {
                if ($('#BVN').val() == '' || $('#BVN').val() == undefined) {
                    alert('Please Enter Customer BVN');
                    return false;
                }
                $('.spinner').css('display', 'block');  //if clicked ok spinner shown

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("BVNMatch", "Transactions")",
                  //  data: '{bvn: "' + $("#BVN").val() + '" }',
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response.message);
                        $('#Firstname').val(response.data.bvn);
                        $('#Surname').val(response.data.is_blacklisted);
                       
                      //  $('#Phone_Number').val(response.data.mobile);

                        $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {

                        alert('BVN Does Not Exist Or Error Processing Request');
                        $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');
                    },
                    error: function (response) {

                        alert('BVN Does Not Exist Or Error Processing Request');
                        $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');
                    }
                });
                });
```

Comment: @david, can you assist?

Comment: Issue resolved by putting the json content as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by putting quotes around the Content JSON

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> BVNMatch()
{
    var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paystack_SecretKey"];
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.paystack.co/bvn/match"))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {secretKey}");
            request.Content = new StringContent("{ **"bvn": \"22******\",\n      "account_number": \"068*****\",\n      "bank_code": \"034\",\n      "first_name": \"uth***\",\n      "last_name": \"ji***\"\n  }"**);
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            BVNMatch myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BVNMatch>(jsonString);
            return Json(myDeserializedClass);
        }
    }
}
```